# Which decimal alignment works under this table code?

Tags: tables

I tried many existing ways to align the following table coefficients but they don't work in this specific code setting (the code shrinks the size of the letters).

And I am very sorry, this code is under the larger document, I am not sure why this part doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[msom,blindrev]{informs3} % current default for manuscript submission

\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{siunitx}

 \def\bibfont{\small}%
 \def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
 \def\bibhang{24pt}%
 \def\newblock{\ }%
 \def\BIBand{and}%


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1} % this reduces the vertical spacing between rows
    \linespread{0.5}\selectfont\centering
    \caption{XXX}
    \centering
    %\footnotesize
    \tabcolsep=0.11cm
    \scalebox{0.7}{
        \begin{tabular}{|lrr|}
            \hline
         XXX&Model 3&Model 4\\
            \hline
            Coors, bottle, 16-pack vs. Budlight, can, 18-pack &0&-0.063\\
            Budlight, bottle, 18-pack vs. Budlight, can, 18-pack &0.106**&0.114**\\
            Miller Lite, can, 18pack vs. Budlight, can, 18-pack &0.094&0.256**\\
            Miller Lite, bottle, 18-pack vs. Budlight, can, 18-pack &0.147***&0.070\\
            Budweiser, bottle, 18-pack vs. Budlight, can, 18-pack &0&0.120**\\
            Budweiser, can, 18-pack vs. Budlight, can, 18-pack &0&-0.017\\
            Budlight, can, 12-pack vs. Budlight, can, 18-pack &0&0.050\\
            \hline
            ***$p<0.005$ **$p<0.05$ &&\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \label{dztable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way, with `\siunitx` and `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{siunitx, threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
 \centering\footnotesize
    \caption{XXX}
    \label{dztable}
    \centering
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
        \begin{tabular}{|l@{\enspace vs.\enspace}lS[table-format=1.3, table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{***}]S[table-format=-1.3, table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{**}]|}
            \hline
         \multicolumn{2}{|l}{XXX} & {Model 3}&{Model 4}\\
            \hline
            Coors, bottle, 16-pack & Budlight, can, 18-pack &0&-0.063\\
            Budlight, bottle, 18-pack & Budlight, can, 18-pack &0.106\textsuperscript{**}&0.114\textsuperscript{**}\\
            Miller Lite, can, 18pack & Budlight, can, 18-pack &0.094&0.256\textsuperscript{**}\\
            Miller Lite, bottle, 18-pack & Budlight, can, 18-pack &0.147\textsuperscript{***}&0.070\\
            Budweiser, bottle, 18-pack & Budlight, can, 18-pack &0&0.120\textsuperscript{**}\\
            Budweiser, can, 18-pack & Budlight, can, 18-pack &0&-0.017\\
            Budlight, can, 12-pack & Budlight, can, 18-pack &0&0.050\\[2pt]
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
 \begin{tablenotes}[para]\smallskip\footnotesize
   \item[**]$p<0.05$
   \item[***]$p<0.005$%
   \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the table. This table looks great but I need small font in order to fit the table on a page (the table is long). The original code had this option.

Comment: Is it possible to use my original code and make adjustments there?

Comment: I've posted the result adding `\footnotesize` at the beginning of the table. But can't you break your table across pages if it's really long? Or print it in landscape? Concerning your code, scaling a table is not very recommended, as it tends to make it hardly readable.

Answer (score 2):

No need to shrink the tabular material with a `\scalebox` "wrapper". I suggest you use the facilities of the `dcolumn` package to align the numbers in columnds 2 and 3 on their decimal markers. Finally, I'd like to recommend creating a more "open" look by (a) removing all vertical lines and (b) using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[msom,blindrev]{article}% I don't have the "informs3" class
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs,caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1} 
    \caption{XXX} \label{dztable}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ld{1.5}d{2.4}}
            \toprule
            XXX & \mc{Model 3} & \mc{Model 4} \\
            \midrule
            Coors, bottle, 16-pack vs.\ Budlight, can, 18-pack
                & 0 & -0.063 \\
            Budlight, bottle, 18-pack vs.\ Budlight, can, 18-pack 
                & 0.106^{**} & 0.114^{**} \\
            Miller Lite, can, 18pack vs.\ Budlight, can, 18-pack
                & 0.094 & 0.256^{**} \\
            Miller Lite, bottle, 18-pack vs.\ Budlight, can, 18-pack 
                & 0.147^{***} & 0.070 \\
            Budweiser, bottle, 18-pack vs.\ Budlight, can, 18-pack 
                & 0 & 0.120^{**} \\
            Budweiser, can, 18-pack vs.\ Budlight, can, 18-pack
                & 0 & -0.017 \\
            Budlight, can, 12-pack vs.\ Budlight, can, 18-pack 
                & 0 & 0.050 \\
            \midrule
            $^{***}\ p<0.005$ $^{**}\ p<0.05$ \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, posted after the OP indicated that the "real" table is too long to fit on a single page: If the table is too tall to fit on a single page and if you don't want to resort to `\scalebox` to reduce its size mechanically, you may want to look into using `longtable` environment instead of a `table`/`tabular` combination.

If the following image strikes you as looking very much like the one shown above, that's certainly not a coincidence. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[msom,blindrev]{article}% I don't have the "informs3" class
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs,longtable}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}  % to align numbers on decimal markers
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}ld{1.5}d{2.4}@{}}
%% Set table headers and footers
\caption{XXX} \label{dztable} \\
\toprule
XXX & \mc{Model 3} & \mc{Model 4} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\emph{(cont'd from previous page)}}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule
XXX & \mc{Model 3} & \mc{Model 4} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{\emph{(cont'd on the following page)}}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% Body of table 
Coors, bottle, 16-pack vs.\ Budlight, can, 18-pack
    & 0 & -0.063 \\
Budlight, bottle, 18-pack vs.\ Budlight, can, 18-pack 
    & 0.106^{**} & 0.114^{**} \\
Miller Lite, can, 18pack vs.\ Budlight, can, 18-pack
    & 0.094 & 0.256^{**} \\
Miller Lite, bottle, 18-pack vs.\ Budlight, can, 18-pack 
    & 0.147^{***} & 0.070 \\
Budweiser, bottle, 18-pack vs.\ Budlight, can, 18-pack 
    & 0 & 0.120^{**} \\
Budweiser, can, 18-pack vs.\ Budlight, can, 18-pack
    & 0 & -0.017 \\
Budlight, can, 12-pack vs.\ Budlight, can, 18-pack 
    & 0 & 0.050 \\
\midrule
$^{***}\ p<0.005$, $^{**}\ p<0.05$ \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this beautiful code. The table, however, must be shrunk due to space limitations in in my paper. Only by shrinking it I could fit that table on the whole page (my example is, maybe, 1/6 of the actual table)

Comment: @Olga - Is the issue (lack of) vertical or horizontal space?

Comment: Oh, the issue is in the size of the letters, not the vertical or horizontal space. Your table is beautiful, exactly what I need but the size is as the actual text. I need them to be smaller. The original code shrank the size quite a bit.

Comment: @Olga - Glad to know my answer was useful. If you feel that the "real" table ends up looking too "small" because of the need to scale down the object, you may want to look into using a `longtable` environment, which allows for page breaks within the table. I've posted an addendum to show how this idea might be applied.